# Switch Case within a Switch Case - Is using fall through cases followed by a new switch case of the same fall through a bad design philosophy?

Tags: c, embedded

I am designing a system where some different states will have the same initial actions, but then depending on what the inital state is, the next state will be different.

I was thinking of using a switch case fallthrough and then using another switch case to determine the end state as follows :

```
switch (State)
{
    case State1:
    case State2:
    case State3:
    //Same actions for all 3 states
    UART_Transmit(&WakeUp);
    UART_Receive(&WakeUpResponse);

    if (WakeUpResponse != WAKEUP_RESPONSE)
    {
         //We retry the ACk -> Ack Response
         UART_Transmit(&WakeUp);
         UART_Receive(&WakeUpResponse);
         if (WakeUpResponse != WAKEUP_RESPONSE)
         {
             UART.State = NewState1;
         }
    }
    //at this point, if WakeUpResponse == WAKEUP_RESPONSE
    //then depending on the initial state, a new state is selected
    if (WakeUpResponse == WAKEUP_RESPONSE)
    {
         //New switch case with the same States as above
         switch(State)
         {
             case State1:
                 UART.State = NewState2;
             break;
             case State2:
                 UART.State = NewState3;
             break;
             case State3:
                 UART.State = NewState4;
             break;
             default:
             break;
    }

    State4:
        //Actions
    break;
    //other cases
}
```

Is this a bad way to go about this situation? I know it's doable strictly coding wise, but I am looking for inputs about maintainability of the code or any other quirks that could come out of that situation.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: put more effort into your question.  The code has to have any sense and to be correct. Otherwise you just waste other people time

Comment: I don't see a problem with this, but to make it less convoluted you could also extract the common code for state 1 through 3 into its own function and then call that from the three cases without fall-through.

Comment: @P__J__ Other than the states name, this is the code as it is right now. Unless I need to post the whole project to make sense of that question (which I doubt is needed), not sure what more is needed for you to not close the question.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error, This is what Eric Postpischill responded as well and it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite this as:

```
static void StateHelper(SomeType NewState)
{
    UART_Transmit(&WakeUp);
    UART_Receive(&WakeUpResponse);

    if (WakeUpResponse != WAKEUP_RESPONSE)
    {
         //We retry the ACk -> Ack Response
         UART_Transmit(&WakeUp);
         UART_Receive(&WakeUpResponse);
         if (WakeUpResponse != WAKEUP_RESPONSE)
         {
             UART.State = NewState1;
         }
    }
    //at this point, if WakeUpResponse == WAKEUP_RESPONSE
    //then depending on the initial state, a new state is selected
    if (WakeUpResponse == WAKEUP_RESPONSE)
        UART.State = NewState;
}

…
switch (State)
{
    case State1:
        StateHelper(NewState2);
        break;
    case State2:
        StateHelper(NewState3);
        break;
    case State3:
        StateHelper(NewState4);
        break;
    case State4:
        //Actions
        break;
    //other cases
}
```

Further, if the state values are small or consecutive or nearly so, it may be desirable to create an array `NewStateLookup` so that it can be written something like:

```
switch (State)
{
    case State1:
    case State2:
    case State3:
        StateHelper(NewStateLookup[State]);
        break;
    case State4:
        //Actions
        break;
    //other cases
}
```